# How to find out if notification has taken place in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, reboot

In my app the user can mark events to get notified when they start. So I have AlarmManager with Notifications. To persist after reboot I save the events to be notified of in the preferences and have a BootReceiver to readd all notifications. But how do I know if a notification has taken place, so that I can remove it from preferences and it won't be displayed again after the next reboot? I don't want just to remove notifications of past events, since the user wants to know if he missed an event.

Comment: What do you trigger using the `AlarmManager`? A `Broadcast`?

Comment: @Shaishav: Yes a Broadcast. The notifications do work, it's just how to know when it's not necessary when to readd them.

Comment: Then why don't yu remove the preference as soon as you show it in the Broadcast receiver itself?

Comment: Oh yes, sure! I was blind and mixed it up with the BootReceiver. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove notification from `Preferences` once you push the notification.

> But how do I know if a notification has taken place

If you mean how do you know if the user has clicked at the notification then simply add the notification id in `Intent` of your *Notification* like so

```
intent.putString(KEY, VALUE);
```

Look for the notification Id in your intent in both `onCreate()` by calling `getIntent()` and within `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` and remove that notification from `Preferences`.

Comment: I'm not sure I made myself clear: Assume the notification was added Monday and the event is Thursday, so the notification should pop-up Thursday. If the phone is rebooted Tuesday the notification should still pop-up Thursday. But if it is rebooted again on Wednesday and is only started again on Friday, the notification should still pop-up. But after another reboot on Saturday it should not pop-up again (because it already did on Friday).

Comment: @Jomo I'm a little confused... did you get the solution from my answer? If not then why mark accepted? If yes then why the comment?

Comment: Sorry. In the end your answer was correct, but I realised it only after the comments from Shaishav to my question.